# Non-destructive universal quantification in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-dif, prolog-setof

A good language for logic programming should allow the programmer to use a language close to the language used by the mathematicians.  Therefore, I have always considered the lack of proper universal quantifier in Prolog an important shortcoming.

Today an idea came to me how to define something much better than `forall` and `foreach`.

### `forany(Var, {Context}, Condition, Body)`

This predicate tries to prove `Body` for all instantiations `Var` gets successively on backtracking over `Condition`. All variables in `Condition` and `Body` are considered local unless listed in `Var` or `Context`. `Condition` is not permitted to modify in any way the variables listed in `Context`, otherwise `forany` won't work correctly.

Here is the implementation (based on yall):

```
forany(V, {Vars}, Goal1, Goal2) :-
    (   bagof(V, {V,Vars}/Goal1, Solutions)
    ->  maplist({Vars}/[V]>>Goal2, Solutions)
    ;   true ).
```

My first question is about the second argument of `forany`. I'd like to eliminate it.

### Now some examples

Construct a list of the first 8 squares:

```
?- length(X,8), forany(N, {X}, between(1,8,N), 
                      (Q is N*N, nth1(N, X, Q))).
X = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64].
```

Reverse a list:

```
?- X=[1,2,3,4,5], length(X,N), length(Y,N),
     forany(I, {X,Y,N}, between(1,N,I),
           (J is N-I+1, nth1(I,X,A), nth1(J,Y,A))).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
N = 5,
Y = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1].
```

Subset:

```
subset(X, Y) :- forany(A, {X,Y}, member(A,X), member(A, Y)).
```

A funny way to generate all permutations of a list without duplicates:

```
permutation(X, Y) :-
     length(X, N), length(Y, N), subset(X, Y).

?- permutation([1,2,3],X).
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
X = [1, 3, 2] ;
X = [2, 1, 3] ;
X = [2, 3, 1] ;
X = [3, 1, 2] ;
X = [3, 2, 1] ;
false.
```

A funny way to sort a list of different integers.  Notice that constraints are used to make the list sorted so most permutations won't be generated:

```
sorted(X) :- forany(A-B, {X}, append(_, [A,B|_], X),
                    A#<B).

?- X=[7,3,8,2,6,4,9,5,1], length(X, N), length(Y, N),
                          sorted(Y), subset(X,Y).

X = [7, 3, 8, 2, 6, 4, 9, 5, 1],
N = 9,
Y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] .
```

### The problem

It seems that this `forany` works brilliantly when constraints are not used. Also, it can be used to generate constraints, but at least on SWI-Prolog there are problems when constraints already have been generated.  The reason for this is that `forany` uses `bagof` and according to the manual of SWI-Prolog:

> Term-copying operations (`assertz/1`, `retract/1`, `findall/3`, `copy_term/2`, etc.) generally also copy constraints. The effect varies from ok, silent copying of huge constraint networks to violations of the internal consistency of constraint networks. As a rule of thumb, copying terms holding attributes must be deprecated. If you need to reason about a term that is involved in constraints, use `copy_term/3` to obtain the constraints as Prolog goals, and use these goals for further processing.

Here is a demonstration of the problem `bagof` creates with constraints:

```
?- X=[A,B,C], dif(C,D), bagof(_, K^member(K,X), _).
X = [A, B, C],
dif(C, _5306),
dif(C, _5318),
dif(C, _5330),
dif(C, D).
```

As you can see, three unnecessary constraints are created.

My second question is if this is a problem only of SWI-Prolog.

And the third question: is there a way to fix this in SWI-Prolog.  The above quote from the manual suggests that `copy_term/3` should be used.  Unfortunately, I don't understand this suggestion and I don't know if it is useful for `forany`.

Comment: In SICStus Prolog, which has much more experience in this area (dif and coroutining from the very beginning 1980s and attributed variables as the first platform since the 1990s), copy_term/2, setof/3 &ct *never* copy constraints — not without reason.

Comment: What about '?- sorted(Xs).`

Comment: @repeat There are two problems with `?- sorted(Xs).` First, in order to ensure that `∀x(p(X)⇒q(X)` Prolog will try to satisfy `q` for all solutions of `p`. This is impossible when `p` has infinite number of solutions. In the particular case of `sorted(Xs)`, when the value of `Xs` is still unknown, potentially this can be an arbitrarily long list. In result, Prolog will try enthusiastically to reach the infinity and it will be us who will have to say it, "Please, stop".

Comment: The second problem is semantic.  According to the specification of `forany` I've given above, "`Condition` is not permitted to modify in any way the variables listed in `Context`, otherwise `forany` won't work correctly." But the definition of `sorted` is such that with `?- sorted(Xs)` Prolog will unify `Xs` first with the empty list, then with a non-empty list and these are not allowed.

Comment: Yes, but even with an infinite number of answers, methods that are not based on `findall/3` &c can give useful results if (1) implication does not hold and (2) the generator enumerates all answers in a fair manner...

Comment: Ad #2: why not check for sufficient instantiation upfront and raise a proper exception in cases of insufficiency?

Comment: @repeat Good idea to raise exception in cases of insufficiency. I don't see how to do this in the short implementation in my original post but in the low level implementation in the answer I have given I added such check.  Which is fantastic: even if there are cases when this `forany` predicate will throw exception or work infinitely, when it produces a solution, this solution is correct. Moreover, if during backtraking `forany` successfuly generates the last solution, we are guaranteed that there are no more solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great news! I was surprised that `bagof` is written in Prolog. By looking at its code I learned that some things I thought are impossible are in fact possible. And just as the manual of SWI-Prolog suggested, `copy_term/3` or rather the similar predicate `copy_term_nat/2` helped.

So with great joy I am able to present a fully working (as far as I can tell) universal quantifier for SWI-Prolog:

```
forany(V, {Vars}, Condition, Body) :-
    findall(V-Vars, Condition, Solutions),
    % For SWI-Prolog.  Can be replaced by Solutions=Clean_solutions in other systems
    copy_term_nat(Solutions, Clean_solutions),
    forany_execute_goals(Clean_solutions, Vars, V, Body).

forany_execute_goals([], _, _, _).
forany_execute_goals([Sol-NewVars|Solutions], Vars, V, Body) :-
    % The following test can be removed
    assertion(subsumes_term(NewVars, Vars)),
    % or replaced by the following more standard use of throw/1:
%   (  subsumes_term(NewVars, Vars)
%   -> true
%   ;  throw('Forbidden instantiation of context variables by the antecedent of forany')  ),
    NewVars = Vars,
    call({Vars}/[V]>>Body, Sol),
    forany_execute_goals(Solutions, Vars, V, Body).
```